# Unable to run nginx because of missing nginx.conf after fresh install on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, ubuntu-20.04

I had trouble with getting my letsencrypt certificate running for nginx so I tried uninstalling everything and starting from scratch.
Now, when I (re)install nginx on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server

```
sudo apt install nginx
```

I cannot start it because the default installation doesn't contain a nginx.conf anymore.

```
ls -lah /etc/nginx
```

output

```
total 32K
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4,0K Jun 24 17:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 90 root root 4,0K Jun 24 17:54 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4,0K Apr 12 10:04 conf.d
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4,0K Apr 12 10:04 modules-available
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4,0K Jun 24 17:50 modules-enabled
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4,0K Jun 24 17:54 sites-available
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4,0K Apr 12 10:04 sites-enabled
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4,0K Jun 24 17:54 snippets
```

I cannot remember that I did anything different than `sudo apt install nginx` when I installed it last time but for some reason the runs-out-of-the-box-installation is no more.

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get remove --purge nginx*
```

The command deletes everything installed by Nginx and also removes the directories. It allows you to then install it completely with the configuration files.

Comment: Please provide your answer in English, otherwise it's going to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It's odd that there is no nginx.conf file, please try to reinstall the package

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt reinstall nginx
```

See if it fixes your problem, and also look around for nginx.conf file in your system

```
sudo find / -iname nginx.conf
```

And finally if your problem is not fixed create nginx.conf your self, you can find a simple config by searching online.

Comment: reinstall didn't do anything, a search didn't find an nginx.conf. a websearch for nginx.conf unfortunatelly is not an option because there are so many different versions of a "default" nginx.conf. everything I found so far is very different than what my nginx.conf was. none of them include the sites-enabled directory, for example and I'm not confident enough with nginx to know what else they are doing different. I want the original repository config file back. but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a third way, which combines both.
This Situation can happen, if you reinstall or install a package, without a clean state.

#### The Debian native Way (apt-get):

- `apt-get clean`
  In case, that there might be a chance that the package was not 100 but only 99.9999% correctly downloaded, fixed for me some rare issues.
- `apt-get update`
  In case, that you have not a valid Repository, or longer not runned
- `apt-get purge nginx*`
  In case, that it is still installed
- `apt-get check`
  Check is a diagnostic tool; it updates the package cache and checks for broken dependencies.
- `apt-get install --reinstall nginx`
  Will reinstall the whole package, remind that it will only install the default packages

#### The One Line Action:

##### With --reinstall (reinstall can also be used, even if not  needed)

`apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get purge nginx* && apt-get check && apt-get install --reinstall nginx`

##### Without confirmation (reinstall can also be used, even if not needed)

`apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get -yy purge nginx* && apt-get check && apt-get install -yy --reinstall nginx`

#### Verify the content

Now it should have a working Nginx installation.

To explain the process, I used this method a while ago to fix a situation when trying to use the Nginx repository. Here's how it works: First, we clean the repository's knowledge, then we fetch it from scratch. We remove Nginx, check for broken dependencies (which shouldn't be an issue at this point), and finally, we reinstall Nginx. You can use `--reinstall` even if Nginx is not currently installed; you could skip all the previous steps and try this command first.

### References:

[Online Man Page: apt-get](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get)